# Reoder TRs in responsive format using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Looking for some assistance on a table I have. Markup is below. Basically at a breakpoint I want to move TR 2 to become TR 4 and TR 5 to become TR 3. Then above the breakpoint I want to reverse the changes, I have some code which is kind of working, but it keeps spawning new TRs as i need the code to work on window.resize to change the table when the screensize is changed.

I've been using insertAfter which I dont think is a good idea... but not sure how to use an array....

Origial TABLE markup :

```
<table>
<tr><td>Row 1 title</td><td>Row 1 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2 title</td><td>Row 2 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3 title</td><td>Row 3 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 4 title</td><td>Row 4 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 5 title</td><td>Row 5 data</td></tr>
</table>
```

So below 500 px the table becomes :

```
<table>
<tr><td>Row 1 title</td><td>Row 1 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3 title</td><td>Row 3 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 5 title</td><td>Row 5 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2 title</td><td>Row 2 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 4 title</td><td>Row 4 data</td></tr>
</table>
```

Then above 500px we go back to :

```
<table>
<tr><td>Row 1 title</td><td>Row 1 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2 title</td><td>Row 2 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3 title</td><td>Row 3 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 4 title</td><td>Row 4 data</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 5 title</td><td>Row 5 data</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry - I've worked out a way - setting the ID value of the TRs - then rearranging with an array - solution below:

```
// set TRs to have an incremental ID
var i=0;
$('table tr').each(function(){
    i++;
    var newID=''+i;
    $(this).attr('id',newID);
    $(this).val(i);
});

// @ and below 500px
var order = [1,3,5,2,4];
      $.each(order, function(){
      $("table").append($("#" + this));
});

// @ and above 501px
var order = [1,2,3,4,5];
      $.each(order, function(){
      $("table").append($("#" + this));
});
```

A great simple solution that keeps things much cleaner than the mess insertAfter was creating!